# Load DataSet with the same relations ,primary keys, and constraints

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, dataset

I was wondering how to load the **DataSet** object exactly the same as the source **DB**, I mean not only the data but the schema also (i.e. the relations, primary keys, constraints etc) because when you use the following:

```
Adapter.Fill(DataSetObject,"TableName")
```

There, you only loads the data and any relations or indexes will be lost and you have to rebuild it all manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do:

```
//First, we load the schema:
Adapter.FillSchema(DataSetObject, SchemaType.Source, "TableName")
//Then, we load the data itself:
Adapter.Fill(DataSetObject, "TableName")
```

Reference--> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301216